# Launch Default Email App when clicked on Table View Cell - IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have this label, which when clicked should take the user to their default email app and compose a message for them.

Can someone please tell me how would I approach to implement this?

[Let's say when someone clicks on feedback, they should be redirected to their default email app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3wvl.png)

Comment: If you want to implement mail feature then try MFMailComposeViewController. which push mail controller where you can send mail.

Answer (score 0):

```
// email 
 let address = "test@test.com"
 let url = URL(string: "mailto://\(address)")
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to send mail.Please read comments to understand code

```
  func sendEmail() {
  // check if device can send mail
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
 // create MFMailComposeViewController object
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
// set delegate to know when email has been sent and perform further tasks
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
// In setToRecipients you can pass array of email to whom you want to send email
        mail.setToRecipients(["someemail.com"])
// In setMessageBody you can pass the email body text
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>some email text</p>", isHTML: true)
        // here you can present the controller
        present(mail, animated: true)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
        //Unable to send Email(email may not be configured in your device)
        // or may be you are using simulator
    }
}
```

Now you can use delegate method to dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController

```
 extension YourViewController : MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate{

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                  didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    // use result for further task
    // Dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the extension to present default Email App on swift 4.

```
import MessageUI 
extension UIViewController : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func configuredMailComposeViewController(recipients : [String]?, subject :
    String, body : String, isHtml : Bool = false,
            images : [UIImage]?) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // IMPORTANT

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(recipients)
    mailComposerVC.setSubject(subject)
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: isHtml)
    //If you want to send images on Mail
    for img in images ?? [] {
        if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) {
            mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(jpegData,
                                             mimeType: "image/jpg",
                                             fileName: "Image")
        }
    }

    return mailComposerVC
}

func presentMailComposeViewController(mailComposeViewController :
    MFMailComposeViewController) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController,
                                   animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
       self.showErrorAlert()
    }
}

public func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                  didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult,
                                  error: Swift.Error?) {
    switch (result) {
    case .cancelled:
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .sent:
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .failed:
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
       self.showErrorAlert()

        })
    default:
        break;
    }
}

func showErrorAlert() {
     let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Failed",
                                                            message: "Unable to send email. Please check your email " +
                "settings and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK",
                                                            style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(sendMailErrorAlert,
                                       animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Now you can call these methods like this.

```
@IBAction func didTapOpenEmailApp(sender: Any) {
    let toRecipients = ["desigredMail@example.com"]
    let subject = "Your subject here"
    let body = "Enter comments here..."
    let mail = configuredMailComposeViewController(recipients: toRecipients, subject: subject, body: body, isHtml: false, images: nil)
    presentMailComposeViewController(mailComposeViewController: mail)
}
```

Happy Coding!